# WebDriver get text from table

Tags: webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use WebDriver and ChromeDriver. How i can fetch text from second table?

I have two tables.
1: [click to see photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyhMB.jpg)

2: [click to see photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlDMC.jpg)

So, When i try download data from second table i download from first :/

```
    WebElement baseTable = driver.findElement(By.className("grey"));
    List<WebElement> tableRows = baseTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tableRows.get(1).getText());
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can u please share URL or paste your code in question.

Comment: @iamsankalp89 sorry but i can not insert url because it is from my college

Comment: i need only download text from one row

Comment: Actually in youe image I am unable to see complete HTML

Comment: but i can send HTML

Comment: send it and i post an answer try this

Comment: U want to print that text right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xpath line this for this '`Actualny tryb'`

```
//td[contains(@class,'strong'][contains(text(),'Actualny tryb')]
```

for this `Rejestracja`

```
//img[contains(@style,'vertical-align:middle')][contains(text(),'Rejestracja bezpo')]
```

Try this code, I don't know `JOptionPane`:

```
driver.get("https://www.usosweb.uj.edu.pl/kontroler.php?_action=katalog2/przedmioty/rejestracjaNaPrzedmiotCyklu&prz_kod=WOZ.PLD-3SDHTTP&cdyd_kod=17%2F18&callback=g_21a73193");

String s = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Status rejestracji przedmiotu')]")).getText();
System.out.println(s);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
```

Comment: My website from i can download text: 
https://www.usosweb.uj.edu.pl/kontroler.php?_action=katalog2/przedmioty/rejestracjaNaPrzedmiotCyklu&prz_kod=WOZ.PLD-3SDHTTP&cdyd_kod=17%2F18&callback=g_3b9fa240

Comment: @david try this

Comment: error when:  
String s = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@style,'vertical-align:middle)][contains(text(),'Rejestracja bezpo')]")).toString();

Comment: String s = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@style,'vertical‌​-align:middle)][cont‌​ains(text(),'Rejestr‌​acja bezpo')]")).getText();  try this

Answer (score 0):

will someone try?
You need download selenium jar from:
http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.5/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar
Download chromedriver: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.32/chromedriver_win32.zip
Import jar file
and copy code:

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.usosweb.uj.edu.pl/kontroler.php?_action=katalog2/przedmioty/rejestracjaNaPrzedmiotCyklu&prz_kod=WOZ.PLD-3SDHTTP&cdyd_kod=17%2F18&callback=g_21a73193");
    Wait();
    String s = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@style,'vertical‌​‌​-align:middle)][co‌​nt‌​ains(text(),'Rej‌​estr‌​acja bezpo')]")).getText();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
```

Comment: wait i will try

Comment: you are amazing! its work. But if I know the value of the left column, can I know the right value? For example, the left column = "Status rejestracji przedmiotu::" and the right = "Studenci mog"

Comment: Wait i will try

Comment: String s = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='layout-c22a']/div/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).getText();
      System.out.println(s);  try this

Comment: Thank you bro!
I got the answer by code:
String ss = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[3]/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]")).getText();